# localStorage getItem in useEffect returning empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to simply get the `quantity` number from `localStorage` and set it to State in my `Nav` component. However, when I use `getItem`, I'm setting an empty array to State and I'm not sure why. Does `quantity` in `localStorage` have to be set within an array in order to work? Or is there something else going on?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Nav() {

  const [qty, setQty] = useState([]);

  useEffect(function() {
    const storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantity'));
    setQty(storageItems);
  }, []);

console.log("nav", qty)
/// returns []

    return (
      <nav className="Nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
        <ul className="nav-links">
          <Link to="/">
            <li>Shop</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/info">
            <li>Info</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/cart">
            <li>Cart {qty}</li>
          </Link>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav;
```

Below is a screenshot of localStorage
[image]

Comment: You read an object from the storage so you probably want it to be `<li>Cart {qty.quantity}</li>`. Anyways, what do you get in the console?

Comment: console log inside use effect to see if there is a value

Answer (score 1):

Setting react state is asynchronous, which might be causing you to see outdated values. In your useEffect, try doing:

```
console.log(storageItems)
```

You could also set up another useEffect for qty:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(qty), [qty])
```

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like `localStorage.getItem('quantity')` will return a string: `{"quantity": 7}`.

To parse that, you'll probably need to convert that to JSON. You can use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantity'))`

Also, your console.log should be inside the `useEffect` to show the result.

Finally, you're setting your initial state to an empty array ([]), but your stored value is a number. You may want to align the two.

Here's a basic working example (assuming your value is already in localStorage):

```
export default function App() {
  const [qty, setQty] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quantity"))
    console.log(result)
    setQty(result.quantity)
  },[])  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{qty}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```